# bug in g++ std::strtod function when used in Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I use 64-bit ubuntu 18.04 upgraded from 16.04.

Make QWidget project, put label on MainWindow and change mainwindow.cpp to

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  std::cout << strtod("3.5", 0) << std::endl;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

There are two new lines

```
#include <iostream>
```

and

```
  std::cout << strtod("3.5", 0) << std::endl;
```

Everything else is untouched.

Build release and run. The result on console will be 3 which is incorrect. The correct value is 3.5. Why?

In the Debug build it works fine. Simmilar non-Qt project works fine.

Comment: Does your locale use `,` as decimal point?

Comment: Let me ***guess***: Your computers regional settings is configured to use the *comma* as decimal separator?

Comment: Use a debugger. is it the `strtod` returning 3 or somehow the formatting set in `cout` truncating the value? You can split the issue in half by doing this as it could be either.

Comment: Also, you should call `std::strtod` and `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: FWIW `std::cout << strtod("3.5", 0) << std::endl;` can just be `std::cout << "3.5" << std::endl;`.  Even `std::cout << strtod(double_string, 0) << std::endl;` can just be `std::cout << double_string << std::endl;`.  No need for `strtod` at all

Comment: @NathanOliver: I am pretty sure that was for example's sake, and that the real program does indeed want to parse a string-from-somewhere for its numerical value. We keep asking for MCVE's, so let's not get too picky if the minimal example isn't really "doing" anything anymore. -- FWIW (2), I would like to point out the existence of [`std::string::stod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). No need to use C functions anymore.

Comment: It IS real application.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

The constructor of QApplication class changes localization. It executes the line

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Then decimal character is not point longer. One of solutions is using Qt's conversion functions, for example QString::toDouble().

Comment: ...from what to what? With a bit of explanation of your environment and what actually happened, this is a *good* answer that might help future visitors.

Comment: The constructor of QApplication has the line

Comment: If that's all, the "correct" solution is, of course, to make your user's locale setting (which is what that line changes the locale to) match your expectation of what the decimal sign is....